# How to make dropdown menu like "delicious" and "google"?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I want to make a dropdown menu like delicious has at this http://delicious.com/search?context=all&p=sql&lc=1 page. In this page click the arrow which is with "Search" button. On click it displays a drop down menu, I want the same menu style but on my page I am having a link, what I want with that link a simple small icon will be displayed and on click of the link or that menu image, a dropdown menu will open.

Google has also done the same thing, http://www.google.co.in/firefox?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official click on the "more" link in the top menu displayed.

I want to use minimal javascript, I prefer JQUERY.

Comment: The solution must be cross-browser!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a lot of JQuery plugins that create a drop down list (Menu) like delicious.
you can use:

1. [JdMenu](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/plugins/jdMenu/)
2. [Drop down menu with jquery](http://ayozone.org/2008/02/06/drop-down-menu-with-jquery/#)
3. [Free CSS Drop-Down Menu Framework](http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/)

Answer (score 5):

I always recommend [Son of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) for menus like this. CSS only, so it works even for users without scripting, and is extremely lightweight and fast for it.

Comment: Those are pretty nice for CSS only!

Comment: the iPhone breaks hover behaviour - worth bearing in mind if you want to accommodate iPhone users.

Answer (score 1):

here is a tutorial on creating the top navigational menu found in google

http://blog.geotitles.com/2011/09/creating-the-new-top-black-bar-found-in-google-and-all-its-products/

Answer (score 1):

You may find this jQuery UI plugin useful - http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

It's built with progressive enhancement in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to set up the menu in Javascript. There are a number of available Javascript libraries available to make this easier. Some of the more popular ones include:

- [Yahoo User Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org)
- [JQuery](http://jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can [try to play](http://dev.iamntz.com/10/playing-with-lists) with some lists. It's an older post on my blog about how you can do a nice breadcrumb with lists and some piece of jquery.